# Get iPhone location update without ending current code thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, location

I'm new to iOS programming and have a basic question.  Up until now I have been getting the location of my iPhone by turning on location updates in my locationManager object.  After that my code ends and I get the location when the delegate method didUpdateLocations is called.

But now I would like to get a single location update and do it from within a code sequence like this:

Line 1:  whatever

Line 2:  whatever

Line 3:  whatever

Line 4:  [locationManager requestLocation]

Line 5:  Wait for location to be updated

Line 6:  Use the new location information

Line 7:  whatever

etc.

But I realize that didUpdateLocations won't be called while the thread above is at "Wait for location to be updated".

What is the proper way to handle this type of situation?

Do I need to somehow request that the location update happen on a different thread so my thread above can keep running in parallel?

Thanks,

-Steve

New edits:

Let's say I do this inside of didUpdateLocations: Set a flag on a global variable to indicate that the location has been updated (i.e. locationUpdated=1) and set location=updated_location.

Then on line 5 (on above example) I wait for locationUpdated == 1.  Then on line 6 I can use the "location" variable.

Does it make sense to write code this way?

In my experiments if I wait in a loop polling for locationUpdated==1 it will prevent didUpdateLocations from being called at all.  So maybe this is a job for GrandCentralDispatch to put the wait loop in a different thread?  I've never used it.

Comment: Do you need the thread to pause while the location is being updated? Or do you want the location updates to occur in the background while normal execution of your program continues after calling for location updates?

Comment: Location updates will always be delivered asynchronously to the delegate method. You don't need to actively "wait". You just do whatever once the delegate method is called. You may need to provide some indication to the user that processing is happening.

Comment: I want my code to pause until I have a valid location fix.  I want to use that location info right on the next line of code (line 6 in my example).  I could update a global variable (containing location) from within the didUpdateLocation method and line 6 will see the updated value of this variable.  Sounds like concurrency to me...  something I have not used yet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright friend, check out this [totally sweet API documentation on the `requestLocation` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation)!

Basically it says:

> This method returns immediately. Calling it causes the location manager to obtain a location fix (which may take several seconds) and call the delegate’s locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method with the result.

That means that if your class subscribes to the locationManager's `delegate`, you can put lines 5, 6, and 7 in your implementation of `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`.

So your code would look like:

```
func whateverFunction() {
    whatever
    whatever
    whatever
    [locationManager requestLocation];
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    use the new location information
    whatever
}
```

I hope this helps!

Edit: Actually I think I misread your post. If that's the case comment and let me know and I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I could do what you are suggesting but I don't want to use the new location info from within the didUpdateLocations method.  I want to use this new info right on the next line (line 6) in my sequence.

Comment: @Morocco5 I have a feeling you are over-complicating this and should figure out a way to refactor your code so you can properly use delegates. It's a very important paradigm of iOS development.